# FATAl Exception during delete record from sqlite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my database Inbox table have column name **path** to keep path of files but when i am trying to delete that record on the base of **path** the FATAL exception is thrown by Emulator.

```
// Deleting single File
public void deleteFile(File file) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_INBOX, KEY_PATH + " = "+file.getPath(),null);
    db.close();
}
```

Exception is :

*`FATAL EXCEPTION:main`*

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteExceprion: unrecognized token:"1kbFile"(code 1):,while compiling :DELETE inbox WHERE path=1kbFile.txt.
```

*1kbFile.txt* is path that i want to delete which is already saved in db.
how can i solve this?

Comment: the sql needs to receive: `path='1kbFile.txt'`

Comment: so add some `+"'"+` s

Comment: i.e.: `KEY_PATH + " = '"+file.getPath() + "'"`  if it works I'll make it an official answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `'` to your file name, like this :

```
db.delete(TABLE_INBOX, KEY_PATH + " = '" + file.getPath() + "'", null);
```

Or you could also try to use separate parameters :

```
String whereString = KEY_PATH + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {file.getPath()};
db.delete(TABLE_INBOX, whereString, whereArgs);
```

Comment: So @user2322360, did that finally help you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ' around the values. E.g.:

```
db.delete(TABLE_INBOX, KEY_PATH + " = '"+file.getPath()+"'",null);
```